# $.mobile.changePage in showing a blank page in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have login function which works but after login in it doesn't take the user to Homepage
instead shows a blank page why isthat?
Ajax with problem:

```
function Login(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/user/adduser/'+$("#loginusername").val(),
headers: {authorization:window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val())},
contentType: "text",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        authorisation = window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val()); //create a variable to pass to the cookie
        createCookie('cookie',authorisation,0); //create our authorisation cookie for the client
        alert("Login Successful!");
        $("#login").hide(); //hide the login button
        $("#logout").show(); //show the logout button
        $("#addreview").show(); //show the add a review button
        $("#adminpanel").show();//show the admin panel page
        $("#loginusername").val(''); //clear the name box
        $.mobile.changePage("#home"); //show the menu

    },
error: function (response) {
    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);

    alert("Error:" + r.error.text);
               }
        });
```

}
The login form

```
  <!-- Login Page-->
  <div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="a">
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-theme="a">
  <a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="a"  data-icon="back"
    data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide"></a>
    <h3 class="pagetitle">
        Login
    </h3>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
              <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
        <fieldset>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="loginusername">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="loginusername" id="loginusername"/>
                        </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="loginpassword">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" value="" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword"/>
                        </div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="checkbox-0" data-role="none"/> Remember me </label>

           <input type="button" data-theme="a" onclick="Login()" name="submit" value="Log in">
             <a href='#signup' data-role="button"> Sign up</a>
        </fieldset>
        </form>

</div>

      </div>
```

and the page where I am trying redirect

```
<!-- Home -->
```

... list view here

The site can be tested here
with username demo and password demo
[enter link description here](http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/client4/#login)
The page I am tryng to load after login[enter link description here](http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/client4/#home)

Comment: yo, Same question twice `:P` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750252/mobile-changepage-displaying-a-blank-page-in-ajax

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete it , but now I have as I made some changes